# NSPredicate multiple field search

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to search multiple fields. Something like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name title contains[cd] %@) AND (title contains[cd] %@",  self.searchBar.text];
```

A search is made on both the name field or the title field.

Also, if anyone knows what a wildcard search would look like I'd appreciate that too.

I tried:

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"* contains[cd] %@",  self.searchBar.text];
```

my error code:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "(name contains[cd] %@) OR (title contains[cd] %@"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you must specify all the properties to examine, since there is no fixed or universal list of properties, and in Objective-C there is no real semantic distinction between a property and any other method.

Second off, to examine multiple properties to see if they contain a search string, you should use `OR`, not `AND`, since your search is satisfied if *any* of the properties match, not *all*.

Otherwise, the syntax you have appears correct (I'm assuming `name title` in the first subpredicate is meant to be just `name`.)

Comment: I tried the syntax and it crashed with both OR and AND. name and title was a typo. thanks for your response.

Comment: For every specifier sequence (e.g. `%@`) you must provide a value, even if the values are identical. So you need to have `self.searchBar.text` twice after your format string. Also, you need to close the second parenthetical in your format string (i.e. end it with a `)` to balance the second `(`).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still reads this post, but I found your problem. You are missing a closing ")" in the second predicate. Here is the correct code:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name title contains[cd] %@) AND (title contains[cd] %@)",  self.searchBar.text];
```

Edit: After testing this I noticed that two format specifiers worked fine with ONE format argument (see code above). When I added a third predicate and format specifier (with only one format argument) it crashed. Either way, you should always have the same amount of format specifiers and format arguments.